# Regular expression to break string C#

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my string:

```
1-1 This is my first string. 1-2 This is my second string. 1-3 This is my third string.
```

How can I break like in C# like;

```
result[0] = This is my first string.
result[1] = This is my second string.
result[2] = This is my third string.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = Regex.Split(text, "(?:^|[\r\n]+)[0-9-]+ ").Skip(1);
```

EDIT: If you want the result in an array you can do `string[] result = lines.ToArray()`;

Comment: @fawad I've tested it with your sample string. Check your code.

Comment: @xanatos \r\n is wrapped in a character class which means either of it can be there. Both are not required.

Comment: @fawad As written both mine and Hasan seems to work correctly http://ideone.com/Xfk0A The problem is that you haven't show us exactly how the string is "composed"

Comment: I want to split according to 1-1, 1-2 and 1-3 not with '\n'.

Comment: I have done it. The correct form was IEnumerable<string> lines = Regex.Split(strText, "(?:^|[1]+)[-0-9]+ ").Skip(1);

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+ )(.*?)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

var str = "1-1 This is my first string.\n1-2 This is my second string.\n1-3 This is my third string.";

var matches = regex.Matches(str);

List<string> strings = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

We use a multiline Regex, so that `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the line. We skip one or more numbers, a `-`, one or more numbers and a space `(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+ )`. We lazily (`*?`) take everything (`.`) else until the end of the line `(.*?)$`, lazily so that the end of the line `$` is more "important" than any character `.`

Then we put the matches in a `List<string>` using Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Lines will end with newline, carriage-return or both, This splits the string into lines with all line-endings.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var lines = Regex.Split( input, "[\r\n]+" );
```

Then you can do what you want with each line.

```
var words = Regex.Split( line[i], "\s" );
```

Comment: end of line is not possible but i want from 1-1, 1-2 and 1-3 to split.